# Rewrite - forward server IP to domain url nginx

Tags: nginx, ip, forwarding, unicorn

I'd like to have the IP of my server be rewritten as a domain name url but I'm having the hardest time figuring out how to make this happen.

For example, when I enter 213.34.54.xxx in the browser, I'd like it to be rewritten as mydomain.com and NOT display the IP address.

My current configuration is as follows:

**/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 2;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
  sendfile        on;

  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mydomain;
}
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mydomain**

```
upstream unicorn {
    server unix:/tmp/unicorn.mydomain.sock fail_timeout=0;
   }

    server {
      listen 80 default;
      server_name localhost;
      root /home/deployer/apps/mydomain/current/public;

      location ^~ /assets/ {
        gzip_static on;
        expires max;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
      }

      try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
      location  / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://unicorn;
      } 

      error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
      client_max_body_size 4G;
      keepalive_timeout 10;
     }
```

I've tried adding this to the server directive in **mydomain** configuration file:

```
rewrite ^ $scheme://mydomain.com$request_uri redirect;
```

but I get a TOO MANY REDIRECTS ERROR in my browsers.

At the very least, I'm able to prevent the IP address from being displayed by using this in the server directive:

```
if ($host !~* ^www\.) {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ http://www.$host$1 permanent;
   }
```

However, this is listed as one of the pitfalls on the nginx site :(

Any insights of what I might be doing wrong would be GREATLY appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

Actually the answer above does not work (at least for me). I suppose since the question has been raised the asker has found his solution, but since I searched on google and a lot of links go here, maybe this solution will help other people, simply add this to your conf file:

```
server {
        server_name 162.13.171.178;
        # you can add other server_name if you need other IPs
        # or domain names such as without the www

        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";

        return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible to use one server block to redirect from many IPs.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443;
  server_name 172.20.0.2 172.20.0.3 172.20.0.4;

  return 301 $scheme://www.yourdomain.com$request_uri;
}
```

There happens to also be a routine PCI compliance finding (leaking private IPs) that can be resolved using this strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a new server instance to the bottom of my domain vhost file as follows worked for me:

```
server {
listen xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80;
server_name xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
rewrite ^ http://example.com$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

**/etc/init.d/nginx reload**

Note: The only reason I added this rewrite is because somehow the IP address for one of my servers ended up in the Google search results, which may cause issues with duplicate content. If this had not happened, I would not have bothered adding the rewrite. You can check to see if your server IP is in the search results by running a search for your IP address:

**site:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx**

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a server block for the rewrite rule. *A single block can accommodate multiple `server_name` elements.*

```
# Say this is your default BIG block

server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name example.com;

  passenger_enabled on;
  rails_env production;
  root /var/www/your_app/current/public/;
}

# Requests made to WWW and directly to the IP address should be
# forwarded to the BIG block

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.example.com 55.55.55.55;

  return 301 http://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: It's possible to list multiple `server_name` entries within one server block.  Your last two blocks could be condensed into one.

Comment: Could anyone help me to edit my solution following the advice of crftr? =)

Answer (score -1):

On your Nginx Configuration file, add the following server block.

```
server {
listen 80 default;
rewrite ^ http://your_domain_name.com$request_uri permanent;
}
```